# How to Get the Dynamic Namespace prefix for XSLT Transformation in WSO2WSB 4.8.0

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

I am Using wso2esb4.8.0. I wish transform my messages into a different format using XSLT transformation.

My request messages are:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:env="http://eai.dd,kk/Envelope"  xmlns:poin="http://eai.mng.par/hhh">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <open:clientRequest>
            <env:EaiEnvelope>
                <env:Domain>1</env:Domain>
                <env:Service>hhh</env:Service>
                <env:ServiceId>1</env:ServiceId>
                <env:Language>En</env:Language>
                <env:UserId>hhh</env:UserId>
                <env:Sender>hhh</env:Sender>
                <env:MessageId>2210201395544</env:MessageId>
                <env:CorrelationId>1</env:CorrelationId>
                <env:GenTimeStamp>1</env:GenTimeStamp>
                <env:SentTimeStamp>1</env:SentTimeStamp>
                <env:Payload>
                    <poin:hhh>
                        <poin:Request>
                            <poin:Operation_Name>kk</poin:Operation_Name>
                        </poin:Request>
                    </poin:hhh>
                </env:Payload>
            </env:EaiEnvelope>
        </open:clientRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:env="http://eai.dd,kk/Envelope"  xmlns:acc="http://eai.mng.par/sd">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <open:clientRequest>
            <env:EaiEnvelope>
                <env:Service>hhh</env:Service>
                <env:Language>En</env:Language>
                <env:UserId>hhh</env:UserId>
                <env:Sender>hhh</env:Sender>
                <env:MessageId>2210201395544</env:MessageId>
                <env:CorrelationId>1</env:CorrelationId>
                <env:GenTimeStamp>1</env:GenTimeStamp>
                <env:SentTimeStamp>1</env:SentTimeStamp>
                <env:Payload>
                    <acc:hhh>
                        <acc:Request>
                            <acc:CustDetails_InputData> 
                                <acc:mno>989352105496</acc:mno>
                            </acc:CustDetails_InputData>
                            <acc:Operation_Name>getv</acc:Operation_Name>
                        </acc:Request>
                    </acc:hhh>
                </env:Payload>
            </env:EaiEnvelope>
        </open:clientRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Both are sample requests that I wish to transform into the formats below as per client request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:acc="http://eai.mng.kman/mng">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <open:getv>
            <acc:mng>
                <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 3 items at this level-->
                <acc:Request>
                    <acc:Operation_Name>getv</acc:Operation_Name>
                    <acc:BasicInfo>
                        <acc:Language>En</acc:Language>
                        <acc:UserId>hhh</acc:UserId>
                        <acc:Sender>hhh</acc:Sender>
                        <acc:MessageId>2210201395544</acc:MessageId>
                        <acc:Operation>getv</acc:Operation>
                    </acc:BasicInfo>
                    <acc:CustDetails_InputData> 
                        <acc:mno>989352105496</acc:mno>
                    </acc:CustDetails_InputData>
                </acc:Request>
            </acc:mng>
        </open:getv>
    </soapenv:Body>  
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:poin="http://eai.mng.kman/hhh">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <open:kk>
            <poin:hhh>
                <poin:Request>
                    <poin:BasicInfo>
                        <poin:Language>En</poin:Language>
                        <poin:UserId>hhh</poin:UserId>
                        <poin:Sender>hhh</poin:Sender>
                        <poin:MessageId>2210201395544</poin:MessageId>
                        <poin:Operation>getv</poin:Operation>
                    </poin:BasicInfo>
                    <poin:Operation_Name>kk</poin:Operation_Name>
                </poin:Request>
            </poin:hhh>
        </open:kk>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Like this various request will come. I need to transform the message in to that desired format. For this I have written a single XSLT which is working fine for this part:

```
<open:kk>
    <poin:hhh>
        <poin:Request>
            <!-- problem here -->
            <poin:Operation_Name>kk</poin:Operation_Name>
        </poin:Request>
    </poin:hhh>
</open:kk>
```

But I am unable to format this part (which should appear in the place indicated above). How do I get the namespace prefix?

```
<poin:BasicInfo>
    <poin:Language>En</poin:Language>
    <poin:UserId>hhh</poin:UserId>
    <poin:Sender>hhh</poin:Sender>
    <poin:MessageId>2210201395544</poin:MessageId>
    <poin:Operation>getv</poin:Operation>
</poin:BasicInfo>
```

Which will take the message and format dynamically but bottom of message part. I am unable to do it.

My XSLT is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/" 
                xmlns:env="http://eai.dd,kk/Envelope" version="1.0">
    <xsl:param name="operation_name"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="UserId"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="Sender"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="MessageId"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="Language"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('open:',$operation_name)}">
            <xsl:element name="Basicinfo">
                <xsl:element name="UserId">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="UserId"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Sender">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Sender"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="MessageId">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="MessageId"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Language">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Language"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//env:Payload/*"></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and simplify it choosing only one of your source examples (the clientRequest one, perhaps). To produce elements with the `poin` prefix, you should declare the corresponding namespace in your stylesheet, and use them in the element names (ex: `poin:Sender`). You will also need qualify the names in your `select` fields matching the source namespace, like you did with the `Payload` field (ex: `env:Sender`).

Answer (score 1):

I just did the implementation of your second output (with second input). I think this will be a good start to develop the other XSLT yourself:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:acc="http://eai.par.sd/gg" xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://eai.par.sd/sd" xmlns:env="http://eai.sd.sd/Envelope" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="soapenv:Body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="open:clientRequest"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="open:clientRequest">
    <open:ff>
        <par:sd>
            <par:Request>
                <par:BasicInfo>
                    <par:Language>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//env:Language"/>
                    </par:Language>
                    <par:UserId><xsl:value-of select="//env:UserId"/></par:UserId>
                    <par:Sender><xsl:value-of select="//env:Sender"/></par:Sender>
                    <par:MessageId><xsl:value-of select="//env:MessageId"/></par:MessageId>
                    <par:Operation><xsl:value-of select="//acc:Operation_Name"/></par:Operation>
                </par:BasicInfo>
                <par:Operation_Name>ff</par:Operation_Name>
            </par:Request>
        </par:sd>
    </open:ff>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*|text()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This creates following output you requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/"
    xmlns:env="http://eai.sd.sd/Envelope"
    xmlns:acc="http://eai.par.sd/gg">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <open:ff xmlns:par="http://eai.par.sd/sd">
            <par:sd>
                <par:Request>
                    <par:BasicInfo>
                        <par:Language>En</par:Language>
                        <par:UserId>par</par:UserId>
                        <par:Sender>par</par:Sender>
                        <par:MessageId>2210201395544</par:MessageId>
                        <par:Operation>dd</par:Operation>
                    </par:BasicInfo>
                    <par:Operation_Name>ff</par:Operation_Name>
                </par:Request>
            </par:sd>
        </open:ff>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```